# How to ensure a function does the entire check of a function?

Tags: java, android

```
    private void startUpTasks() {
    Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

    //  If the activity has never started before...
    if (isFirstRun) {
        //  Launch app intro
        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EnterInfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply();

        initializeUserInfo();
    } else {
        getUserInfo();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Basically I have it narrowed down that the check goes straight to the else statement which doesn't allow a user to register for the first time. I'm using Firebase Auth to register a new user and store them in Firebase's Database.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that is related to Firebase.

Comment: It's not a Firebase issue really so I changed the wording of the question.

Comment: Did you make the registration before?

Comment: If I put the "EnterInfoClass" into the else statement it'll allow for a user to be brought brought to a class in which they input their personal details but it'll also bring an already registered user to that class too and they'll have to enter their personal details (height, weight etc, it's a fitness app) each time which is something I can't have.

Comment: Please don't use tags that don't refer to the correct technology.

Comment: maybe you have put `false` for `isFirstRun` in a previous install of the app, please clear app data and try again.

Answer (score 0):

**Okay look I will try to help you understand what you should do:**

I assume that you want the user to go to `EnterInfoActivity` only if they didn't register before, and you are using sharedPreferences to do so. If that is the case:

**This code:**

```
    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply();
```

**Must be added after the user registered the details in the `EnterInfoActivity`**

**Other than that**

If you want to test the functionality again, you must uninstall the app to clear shared preferences data and run the app again to test again as if you are a new user that installed the app, this way `if-statement` must run instead of `else`.

Comment: Turns out after about 20 hrs of changing code, an uninstall was the key. All a learning curve I suppose.... Thanks

Comment: If that answer helped make sure to accept so other know, GoodLuck.